# how to subtract value of two same array in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have two array like this below.

```html
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [sply_ty] => INTRB2B
            [nil_amt] => 0
            [expt_amt] => 0
            [ngsup_amt] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [sply_ty] => INTRB2C
            [nil_amt] => 0
            [expt_amt] => 0
            [ngsup_amt] => 0
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [sply_ty] => INTRAB2B
            [nil_amt] => 76.77
            [expt_amt] => 38.39
            [ngsup_amt] => 33.01
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [sply_ty] => INTRAB2C
            [nil_amt] => 0
            [expt_amt] => 0
            [ngsup_amt] => 0
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [sply_ty] => INTRB2B
            [nil_amt] => 0
            [expt_amt] => 0
            [ngsup_amt] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [sply_ty] => INTRB2C
            [nil_amt] => 0
            [expt_amt] => 0
            [ngsup_amt] => 0
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [sply_ty] => INTRAB2B
            [nil_amt] => 4
            [expt_amt] => 0
            [ngsup_amt] => 1
        )

)
```

here i want a final array which contains subtracted value of same supply type .

```html
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [sply_ty] => INTRB2B
            [nil_amt] => 0
            [expt_amt] => 0
            [ngsup_amt] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [sply_ty] => INTRB2C
            [nil_amt] => 0
            [expt_amt] => 0
            [ngsup_amt] => 0
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [sply_ty] => INTRAB2B
            [nil_amt] => 72.77
            [expt_amt] => 38.39
            [ngsup_amt] => 32.01
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [sply_ty] => INTRAB2C
            [nil_amt] => 0
            [expt_amt] => 0
            [ngsup_amt] => 0
        )

)
```

How can I get this array without using much foreach or may be using mysql

Comment: you need to share database stracture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $initial and $substract as the inital arrays.

Straight forward solution is just finding the key from one in the other.

```
foreach($substract as $sub) {
    foreach($initial as $index => $obj) {
        if ($obj->sply_ty == $sub->sply_ty) {
            $initial[$index]->nil_amt -= $sub->nil_amt;
            $initial[$index]->expt_amt -= $sub->expt_amt;
            $initial[$index]->ngsup_amt -= $sub->ngsup_amt;
        }
    }
}
```

This loop is off course far from optimal. Creating a lookup first (or even once)

i.e:

```
$lookup = [];
foreach($initial as $index => $obj) {
    $lookup[$obj->sply_ty] = $obj;
}

foreach($substract as $sub) {
    if (isset($lookup[$sub->sply_ty])) {
        $lookup[$sub->sply_ty]->nil_amt -= $sub->nil_amt;
        $lookup[$sub->sply_ty]->expt_amt -= $sub->expt_amt;
        $lookup[$sub->sply_ty]->ngsup_amt -= $sub->ngsup_amt;
    }
}

$result = array_values($lookup);
```

Answer (score 1):

Fastest way will be do it in mysql, ex.:

```
SELECT 
a.sply_ty AS sply_ty,
(a.nil_amt - b.nil_amt) AS nil_amt,
(a.expt_amt - b.expt_amt) AS expt_amt,
(a.ngsup_amt - b.ngsup_amt) AS ngsup_amt
FROM source AS a
LEFT JOIN subtract AS b ON a.sply_ty = b.sply_ty
WHERE ...
```

To make it much faster use `foreign key` to join `subtract` table. If could be more then one matching records in `subtract` table you should use `SUM` and `GROUP BY` on `subtract` table, ex.:

```
SELECT 
a.sply_ty AS sply_ty,
(a.nil_amt - SUM(b.nil_amt)) AS nil_amt,
(a.expt_amt - SUM(b.expt_amt)) AS expt_amt,
(a.ngsup_amt - SUM(b.ngsup_amt)) AS ngsup_amt
FROM source AS a
LEFT JOIN subtract AS b ON a.sply_ty = b.sply_ty
WHERE ...
GROUP BY a.sply_ty, a.mil_amt, a.expt_amt, a.ngsup_amt;
```

On the other side, if you must do it in PHP use `array functions` instead of `foreach`, it should be faster, ex.:

```
$source = array( ... );
$subtract = array( ... );

// apply function for every element of array with using $subtract
array_walk(
    $source,
    function (&$item) use ($subtract) {
        // find matching subtract items, return array
        $subItems = array_filter(
            $subtract,
            function ($s) use ($item) {
                return $s->sply_ty == $item->sply_ty;
            },
        );
        // if its empty, just do nothing
        if (empty($subItems)) {
            return;
        }
        // if not empty get first element as only exists that I suppose, 
        // if there will be more then one element to subtract use another loop to subtract every
        $subItem = current($subItems);
        $item->nil_amt -= $subItem->nil_amt;
        $item->expt_amt -= $subItem->expt_amt;
        $item->ngsup_amt -= $subItem->ngsup_amt;
    }
);
```